# How can I delete some of my old questions?

Tags: support, deletion

I want to delete some of my old questions that are off-topic and received downvotes. Frankly, they were bad questions because I was not so mature 3 years ago.

Can someone please tell me what I should do? Should I flag them with deletion request?

Comment: There is a `delete` option at the end of the question along with `share`, `edit`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [FAQ on Meta SE on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222):

> You can't delete your own *question* if it:
>
> - has an [answer with upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)
> - has an accepted answer
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
> - [has an answer with an awarded bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele?cb=1)
> - has at least one other question that is marked as a duplicate of your question
>
> You can't delete any of your own posts if [you've already deleted five of your own posts on the same day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85523/you-have-already-deleted-5-of-your-own-posts-today-further-deletes-are-blocked).

If your post does not satisfy any of these exceptional criteria, then you can delete it by clicking on the "delete" button beneath the question, alongside the "share", "edit" and "flag" buttons.

Flagging a moderator for deletion is not the way to go, because if you can delete your own post then you should take the action yourself, and if you cannot then there are probably good reasons for why that is so. The [FAQ on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) has some more details on this point, you can see the section titled "If I flag my post with a request to delete it, what will happen?"

---

Even if you have the ability to delete your old questions that you feel are off-topic and/or are poorly received, consider trying to improve them using the knowledge you have gained so far. This will be a gain for both yourself as well as the community.

Indeed, as [@amWhy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9003/amwhy) points out in the [comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32345/how-can-i-delete-some-of-my-old-questions/32348?noredirect=1#comment144388_32348) [below](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32345/how-can-i-delete-some-of-my-old-questions/32348?noredirect=1#comment144391_32348), one's deleted posts are also taken into account when one receives a post ban for low-quality contributions. Though in your specific case this doesn't seem to be an issue, most new users are unaware of this fact and think that deleting their downvoted/closed posts will help bypass the ban, whereas it is not so. Hence, the advice to improve one's poorly received posts is to be doubly encouraged.

The [FAQ on post bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) goes into greater detail regarding the above points. It might also be useful to go through the suggestions given in the Help Center article [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

---

If you are absolutely sure that you want to proceed with deletion and are unable to do so yourself, you might try posting links to those questions in the chatroom [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/cured) and requesting help in closing and deleting. ([I once did so](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47759689#47759689) for one of my questions that was an $n$-fold duplicate.)

Comment: But [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655044/geometrical-representation-of-complex-numbers) which I posted satisfies the first three conditions but it is still eligible for deletion. It has a [delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQi1u.png) option.

Comment: @SarGe Try clicking on the delete button, you should receive an error message.

Comment: Yes! I didn't receive any message but the question remains unchanged even after clicking the delete button.

Comment: @SarGe Ah, the lack of an error message is possibly because you are on mobile. When I try on one of my questions I receive the following banner: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5PSH.png

Comment: The only thing I would add, particularly for users with less rep than the asker who asked this question, is that a user's question-asking record included all downvoted and deleted posts, which can lead to question-bans, depending on the number of deleted questions, and the vote count on them.  Some users mistakenly believe that deleting questions with negative score will improve their standing, but depending on how many are deleted, deleting too many of them can trigger a question ban. So I concur with Brahadeesh: ...

Comment: ... "Even if you have the ability to delete your old questions that you feel are off-topic and/or are poorly received, consider trying to improve them using the knowledge you have gained so far."

Comment: @amWhy That's an important point, especially for newer users as you say. May I incorporate your comment into the answer?

Comment: Yes, feel free to do so, @Brahadeesh!

Comment: @amWhy Thank you, and done :) Hope it's alright.

Comment: Well done, @Brahadeesh!